# How to Establish Functionize DB explorer connection for kdb+?

Tags: jdbc, proxy, kdb, tunnel, jdbc-odbc

I have tried to connect my kdb+ data base to functionize DBexplorer.

[image: Functioniz DBexplorer]

I have followed their installation steps. But I can't establish a connection for kdb+. They have mentioned like using functionize tunnel protocol, we can create proxy port and get the data via proxy port in Functionize DBexplorer tool. But there is no visible for kdb+ connectivity.

[image: Steps to create tunnel port]

I have installed the prerequisite properties like java, maven, JDBC and javakdb.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? If it's not in kdb you can tell other DB connection protocol like postgres, oracle, etc...

Thanks in Advance!